# HTML5 for IE 8 or below version

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have developed website using HTML5,bootstrap in asp.net. It is working fine in every browser except IE9 and below version. Please help regarding this. Should I write separate code for those browser?

Comment: With some caveats bootstrap 3 does [support ie8/9](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9) - if you are having issues then check the html doctype/http-equiv is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you 3 points--

**No. 1**

Try to use the bootstrap from local files. I.e don't use the cdn save it locally and use it.

**No.2**

Install respond js to make it work in IE8

**In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of respond.js to enable media query support.**---this is written in bootstrap docs.

[respond can be found here](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

**No.3**
Check meta tag http-equiv should be set to X-UA-COMPATIBLE 
your meta tag should look like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are probably cases dependent on your specific situation and used code which you will need to handle differently in <= IE9. However, take a look at [HTML5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), which enables the use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy browsers.

By the way, if you're using Bootstrap, then this is already included in their [basic template](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) by this piece of code:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```